# How to have 'required' in my textarea without executing the 'onclick' function immediately?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried putting `required`in my textarea. But it won't work because my `onclick="displayText()"` function executes right away. How can I require my textarea get filled out first without executing the onclick right away? Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Word Counter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="input-page">
      <h1>Word Counter</h1>
      <form action="">
        <textarea id="inputted-text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea>
        <br />
      </form>
      <button onclick="displayText()">COUNT</button>
    </div>

    <div id="count-page" style="display: none;">
      <h1>Your Text:</h1>
      <p id=display-user-text></p>
      <div>
         <h1 id="word-count">Count: </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const displayText = () => {
  const inputPage = document.getElementById("input-page");
  const countPage = document.getElementById("count-page");
  inputPage.style.display = "none";
  // get user's inputted text
  const inputtedText = document.getElementById("inputted-text");
  const inputtedTextValue = inputtedText.value;
  // diplay user's inputted text
  document.getElementById("display-user-text").innerText = inputtedTextValue;
  countPage.style.display = "block";
  console.log(countWords(inputtedTextValue));
};

const countWords = (str) => {
  return str.split(" ").length;
};

const renderWordCount = () => {
  document.getElementById("word-count") = wordCount;
};
```

Bonus:
How can I display the count of my words besides the `Count:` header, instead of just having it on my console?

Comment: One problem is that your id `display-user-text` needs to be in quotes. However even in fixing this, you may still have some logical errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want the system to issue a warning when the text-area is empty. You can do this by adding If-else condition expressions to your codes.

```js
const displayText = () => {
  const inputPage = document.getElementById("input-page");
  const countPage = document.getElementById("count-page");
  const inputtedText = document.getElementById("inputted-text");
  const inputtedTextValue = inputtedText.value;

  if (inputtedText.value !== "") { // normal flow will continue if the text-area is not empty
    inputPage.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("display-user-text").innerText = inputtedTextValue;
    countPage.style.display = "block";
  } else { // if the text-area is empty, it will issue a warning.
    alert("this area required")
  }

  console.log(countWords(inputtedTextValue));
};

const countWords = (str) => {
  return str.split(" ").length;
};

const renderWordCount = () => {
  document.getElementById("word-count") = wordCount;
};
```

```html
<div id="input-page">
  <h1>Word Counter</h1>
  <form action="">
    <textarea id="inputted-text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea>
    <br />
  </form>
  <button onclick="displayText()">COUNT</button>
</div>

<div id="count-page" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Your Text:</h1>
  <p id="display-user-text"></p>
  <div>
    <h1 id="word-count">Count: </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```